# How can I remove a bit from a jackhammer that got stuck in concrete?

Tags: demolition

I was trying to [jack hammer a hole through my foundation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/274875/5778). This turned out to be a herculean task. I blame the old concrete from 1950 which is filled with rocks. I keep getting my bits stuck in the foundation. What's the best way to get them out?

Is there a chemical or something that you can spray around a bit to help free it? Is this something I should try next time?

Answer (score 1):

**I'm not going to mark this answer as chosen**, but in order to get my bits out what I ended up doing was taking the big (1-1/8-hex bit) demolition hammer, the one that got the first pointed bit stuck and I removed the demo hammer from the bit that was stuck in the ground. The hammer came with another flat-chisel bit which I was able to use to free the pointed-chisel bit.

In the process though I put a lot of wear on the flat-chisel bit since I basically had to chisel down the top and the bottom of the flat-point bit.

Comment: why asking a question if you have the answer

Comment: @Ruskes For the same reason I said I wouldn't mark the answer as chosen: because I'm not satisfied with it. It's a starting place. And for the same reason there are other parts of the question not in the answer _"Is there a chemical or something that you can spray around a bit to help free it?"_ But, even if I had an answer and didn't want further input. It's _encouraged_ to ask and self-answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Self-answered questions are not only perfectly acceptable here, @Ruskes, [they're actually encouraged](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)!

Comment: To the question itself, I don’t have an answer. I’d suggest a strategy of push/ pull/ clear debris to keep this from happening in the first place.

Comment: You might also try drilling multiple holes with an actual drill bit and then trying to break the web between them with a chisel.

Comment: I suspect the answer might be "don't hammer down so far that the bit gets stuck." Hammer down in stages.

Answer (score -1):

Just had several holes drilled through concrete: 3 at 2" diameter and 1 at 4" and then 2 at 7" in diameter.

These were done with a type of pillar drill and big core drills - all very clean holes, the setup time was about 10 minutes as a bolt needs to be used to secure the pillar drill. Each hole of 7" through a thickness of 10" took about 5 minutes.

I hate to think how long it would have taken to drill drill multiple smaller holes around the diameter...

This link shows the model of drill they used:

```
https://www.hirehere.ie/diamond-core-drill
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @brhans yes it does - use the correct tool for the job :)

Comment: This is a reasonable answer for "how do I make a large hole in my concrete floor", but it doesn't address the OPs _current_ issue (possibly due to using the wrong tool) of "how do I unstick the bit?".